# Replication timinig in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, replication, datastax-enterprise

Is there any way to test how long it takes for replication to complete? For example, if i had a 9 node cluster (3 dc's 3 nodes each, replication factor of 3/3) and do an insert with Local_Quorum, is there a metric that shows how long it took that data to replicate to all of the replicas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a general idea as of 3.8 with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11569 via the `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=CrossNodeLatency` mbean. This includes all messages (ie gossip, streaming, reads) not just writes though so its not exact.

Comment: Im currently using DSE and opscenter specifically - would this be the equivelent of the "Datacenter Messaging Latency" and "Node Messaging Latency" metrics?

Comment: Yes. You can check in definitions directory in `cassandra-metrics-3.10.0.json` to know what the metric is backed with.